# Cannot read property 'data' of null using objects

Tags: javascript, object

I'm currently learning how to implement a Binary Search Tree in Javascript. I came across an error "*Cannot read property 'data' of null*" which I was able to fix but I still can't understand why it gave that error.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
var test = function(){
    this.a = null;

    this.constr = function(val){
        this.data = val;
        this.left = null;
        return this;
    };

    this.create = function(num){
        var b = this.a;

        if(b === null)
            //this.a = new this.constr(num);
            b = new this.constr(num);
        else
            b.left = new this.constr(num);
    };
};

var c = new test();

c.create(5);
c.create(20);
console.log(c.a.data);
console.log(c.a.left);
```

The code that I commented at line 14 : **this.a = new this.constr(num);** works fine but the one below it gives the error described. Why is that? Why can **b.left** be assigned but not **b** itself? Isn't **b** and **this.a** referencing the same object?

Comment: Assigning to `b` does not assign to `this.a`. A variable is never a reference to a property (unless you are using `with`). Yes, *when* `b` and `this.a` do reference the same object, then for *changing a property* of that object does not make a difference. But `b` holds the value `null` as you established in the condition.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for replying I find your answer really helpful and made me realize what I was doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you assign `this.a` to `b` it holds reference of `null` that is assigned `this.a`, it no way references the property `a`; when you assign new value to `b = new this.constr(num);` the `b` variable references to new object, rather than altering property `a` of that object.